# Java Thread state when performing I/O operations

Tags: java, java-threads, thread-synchronization

Suppose a Java thread performs some I/O operation like reading a file with traditional blocking Java I/O.

The question is: What is the state of the thread while waiting?

I don't know if it is RUNNING (doing some active wait) or WAITING (maybe there is some kind of monitor that wakes up the thread when file data is ready).

How can I find it out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A thread that is blocked in an I/O syscall should be in RUNNABLE state, according to my reading of the javadocs.

> `public static final Thread.State RUNNABLE`
>
> Thread state for a runnable thread. A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual machine *but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating system* such as processor.

The other possible thread states are far more tightly specified, and the respective specifications make them clearly inapplicable.

I have confirmed this by testing (with OpenJDK Java 8 on Linux).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            System.in.read();   // Block for input
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        t.start();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("State: " + t.getState());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, hypothetically, if you designed your application so that one thread handed off I/O requests to second thread, then the first thread would be in WAITING (or possibly BLOCKED) state waiting for the I/O thread to deliver.  However, normal Java I/O doesn't behave like that.  The thread requesting I/O is the one that makes the syscall.

> How can I find it out?

- Write tests; see above.
- Deep-dive the OpenJDK source code.